# Add motion between a list of material cards and a detail activity

Tags: android, material-design, motion

How can I add a motion between those two activities ?

Left : RecyclerView ______________________ Right : DetailActivity

[image]

Those images and styles are from the material design guidelines https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/material-design-style/#0

Comment: Scene Transition -> Look out for Transition API in android

Comment: check the shared element transition in android. You can also look at the example https://medium.com/@DeepakDroid/share-element-transition-between-recycler-view-and-fragment-8ce5084fd7a2#.glxk1s7h8

Comment: Thanks, will take a look

Comment: The pesto example from here is exactly what I'm looking for https://material.io/guidelines/motion/material-motion.html#material-motion-how-does-material-move
I found the source code in github for Flutter here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/flutter_gallery  
Can't find the source code for Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These guidelines helped me a lot : https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition#1-enable-window-content-transitions

This is the code from my Handler

```
public void onCardClick(View view, Module module) {
    final Context context = view.getContext();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.MODULE, module);

    View image = view.findViewById(R.id.card_image);
    View description = view.findViewById(R.id.card_description);

    Pair<View, String> p1 = Pair.create(image, "image");
    Pair<View, String> p2 = Pair.create(description, "description");

    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat
            .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(mActivity, p1, p2);

    context.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
}
```

I have also added transitionName in both of my activities

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/card_image"
    android:transitionName="image" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/card_description"
    android:transitionName="description" />
```